# Adding filename/domain name before result of cat

Tags: linux, bash, dig

When i run below command I got result like

```
dig +short ns kinoafisha.info | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print}' >> test.csv
dig +short ns linux.com | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print}' >> test.csv
```

Result

```
ns2.kinoafisha.info., ns1.kinoafisha.info.
ns1.dnsimple.com., ns2.dnsimple.com., ns3.dnsimple.com., ns4.dnsimple.com.
```

(my question) **I am trying like (1st domain name and then the DNS)**

```
kinoafisha.info, ns2.kinoafisha.info., ns1.kinoafisha.info.
linux.com, ns1.dnsimple.com., ns2.dnsimple.com., ns3.dnsimple.com., ns4.dnsimple.com.
```

PS: I will all domains in a loop (CSV) and then run command like

Loop

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   dig +short ns $line | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print}' >> test.csv

done < domains.txt
```

I need to run multiple commands for 100 domains like `dig +short ns` and `dig +short a` and `dig +short mx` and so on... I want to print result horizontal. please suggest.

i try

```
   dig +short ns $line | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print $line,$0}' >> test.csv
```

but didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **echo** to concatenate line value and your dig command output:

```
echo "$line ,"  $(dig +short ns $line | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print $0}') >> test.csv
```

Comment: suddently my bash code stop working and when i run sh dns.sh ... it show my code instead of execution ))